# How long for 14.04 installation to repartition disk

Tags: 14.04, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

So I wanted to replace 12.04 alongside W7 by 14.04 alongside W7. Trying the upgrade path resulted in a crash, grub badly mutilated apparently. So tried a fresh install. 14.04 recognises W7 so I ask Ubuntu to install alongside. It warns me that repartitioning can take a long time. So I guess it could not see the remains of "upgraded" 12.04. So I go for the repartition in the hope that grub will return. How long should I wait? HDD humming happily for 30 hours so far. 
AMD 64 bit 8 core and 400GiB drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have unused partitions of a previous (botched) Ubuntu installation, you should choose “something else“ instead of “alongside” and use the pre-existing partition(s).

The duration of shrinking the Windows partition depends on the amount to shrink, the fill rate of its file systems, and the throughput of your hard drive. 30 h for <400 GB sounds a bit much though. If your machine has a disk activity light and it isn't constantly lit or blinking, you can abort without (further) damage.

Comment: Thanks, should I kill this repartitioning process (power down) - leaving the entire disk a mess and try what? Will W7 still be there?

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly.